# maven project not recognizing some artifacts

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am new to Maven, It might be stupid question. My problem is I have created dynamic web project in Eclipse Luna version. I have added some artifacts in pom. JAXRS and DOM4J. It downloaded all jars.

I am able to import JAXRS class in my code with out adding jaxrs in lib file.
but i am not able to access DOM4J class. I am using web-sphere as my server.

Please help me to fix dom4j issue. Thanks in advance.

POM file.. I have removed some entries this post.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>.......</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>

      <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
      </build>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
.....
.....
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

My Class path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/WebSphere Application Server v8.0 JRE">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path=".apt_generated">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/com.ibm.ws.ast.st.runtime.runtimeTarget.v80/WebSphere Application Server v8.0">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

I am using Websphere 8 as my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Jar is downloaded as you mentioned then simply do this, in eclipse if you added Maven from Market place then it well and good if not then add this and then

```
Right click on your Project->Maven->Update the Project
```

It will resolve the issue related to dependency.

OR

try this command

```
mvn clean -U

mvn clean install -U

mvn eclipse:eclipse -U
```

See [Maven: The Complete Reference, 6.1.11. Downloading and Verifying Dependencies](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-deps-option) or `mvn --help`:

> ```
> -U,--update-snapshots    Forces a check for missing
>                          releases and updated snapshots on
>                          remote repositories
> ```

Comment: It worked. I have used command. Can you please tell me what is the issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `-U`  is used to update forcefully will give you more details